# Chartkick google geo-chart - is it possible to use a string as tooltip value?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I'm using Chartkick to display this map using the Google api:

```
geo_chart @final_output, library: {backgroundColor: "transparent", width: 400}
```

Right now if I pass it a string as the 2nd value it won't work. But an integer will.

```
[['Canada','cat'],['United States',4]]  <- first one won't work
```

Is there a way from rails to make this happen? I checked the google docs and chartkick and it does not mention it anywhere.

Thanks!

for Reference: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#important

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working in text mode, and in that case the second argument is the text size - so will need to be a number. From the documentation you link to:

> Text mode format
>
> The label is entered in the first column, plus one optional column:
>
> Text label [String, Required] A specific string address (for example,
>   "1600 Pennsylvania Ave"). Text size [Number, Optional] The second
>   column is an optional numeric column used to assign the size of the
>   label. If this column is not present, all labels will be the same size.